# QWebpage only fetches HTML once, and cannot be invoked again

Tags: python, pyqt4, qwebpage

I have a code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

class TextBrowser(QtCore.QObject):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.some_url = url

        self.html_source = None

        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.page = QWebPage()

        self.page.loadFinished.connect(self.get_html)

        self.page.mainFrame().load(self.some_url)

    def get_html(self):
        frame = self.page.mainFrame()
        self.html_source = unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit()


def get_html_source(some_url):
    app = QApplication([])
    browser = TextBrowser(QtCore.QUrl(some_url))
    app.exec_()
    return browser.html_source
```

So now, if i run:

```
print get_html_source('http://www.google.com')
```

It's okay, and returns a html source from the page `http://www.google.com`. But if I run another next one like this:

```
print get_html_source('http://www.google.com')
print get_html_source('http://www.yahoo.com/')
```

This executes only once, outputs google's html source but after that the PyCharm returns "Process finished with exit code 139" and second call of get_html_source() doesn't executing.

I need to iterate through some url list and get source code from them using by Qwebpage, but my implementation doesn't work.

Where can i find some info about my needs or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are creating and executing multiple QApplications which, since they have event loops running, kill one-another. You should only ever have one QApplication and call exec_ one it exactly once. Question: do you actually need the GUI here?

Comment: No, it's a console application without GUI.

Comment: In that case you should be using QCoreApplication; but what's wrong with python's urllib? `urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()` (python3 version) `urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()` (python 2 version)

Comment: QWebpage returns whole html source with supporting javascript. urlib doesn't, as i know. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following. `exec_` starts the event loops (once), and two separate pages are running:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

class TextBrowser(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.some_url = url

        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        self.page = QWebPage()
        self.page.loadFinished.connect(self.get_html)
        self.page.mainFrame().load(self.some_url)

    def get_html(self):
        frame = self.page.mainFrame()
        self.html = frame.toHtml()
        self.close()


def get_html_source():
    app = QApplication([])
    urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com/']
    out = []
    for u in urls:
        t = TextBrowser(QtCore.QUrl(u))
        t.exec_()
        out.append(t.html)
    print(out)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_html_source()
```

This program has no means to exit as it stands - I suppose you wanted to do more with the HTML than print it anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
But with that implementation i wouldn't iterate through list of URL-s.
Basically i need something that:
`urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com/']
for url in urls:
    html_source = get_html_source(url)`
But in that way it returns html_source only from last url in the list.

Comment: You have a syncronisation issue here - you have to wait for the loads to complete. In this case, you would need a QTimer, which after some number of seconds polls the TextBrowsers to get the HTML. I hope that's enough for you to go on.

Comment: Can you suggest please where should i place that Qtimer?

Comment: Edited for you. Note that QApplication is not explicitly executed here, so can get segfault upon exit - it's up to you what to do once you have `out`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I didn't know that i can use TextBrowser(QtGui.QDialog) instead of TextBrowser(QtCore.QObject). And actually don't understand what is difference between that object declarations. I hope i'll figure out this in future.
Now i've got some experience in that stuff.

Comment: The difference is exactly that you can call exec_, like a dedicated mini-application (that is exactly how dialogs normally work).